# Write on an Arrow math symbols

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

somebody know how to put math symbols on an arrow of given length ?

I know that I can put symbols on arrow using the command:

```
\xlongrightarrow{\makebox[2cm]{ 123 }}.
```

The problem is that I can not put math symbols at the place of '123'.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Use `\xrightarrow{abc}`; there's no reason for making overlong arrows.

Answer (score 6):

`\makekebox` turn its content into text mode, so

```
$\xlongrightarrow{\makebox[2cm]{ $\alpha$ }}$
```

will do what you like to obtain:

[image]

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{extarrows}

\begin{document}
$\xlongrightarrow{\makebox[2cm]{ $\alpha$ }}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here my answer.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\Huge
$\xrightarrow[\text{bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}]{\text{ccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}}$
\end{document}
```

or

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\Huge
$\xrightarrow{\text{ooooooooooooooooooooo}}$
\end{document}
```

or

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\Huge
$\xrightarrow[\text{$\alpha$$\alpha$$\alpha$$\alpha$$\alpha$}]{\text{$\alpha$$\alpha$$\alpha$$\alpha$}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, the OP wants a long arrow but with math mode symbols over it, rather than text mode.

Answer (score 3):

i only know how to do that with [tikz](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/arrows/) package:

```
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]
    \node[text=black,anchor=center,inner sep=1pt] (#1) {#2};}
      \begin{align*}
        \tikzmark{a}{a}+\tikzmark{b}{b} & =\tikzmark{c}{c} \\[1em]
        \tikzmark{sums}{Sumanden} & =\tikzmark{sum}{Summe}
       \phantom{\hspace{8cm}} %%<---versatz von rechts (!) 
      \end{align*}
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[blue,thick,->] (sums.north) to [bend left=0] node[anchor=south]{$\pi$}(a.south);}
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[blue,thick,->] (sums.north) to [bend left=0] node[anchor=south]{a}(b.south);}
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[blue,thick,->] (sum.north) to [bend left=0] node[anchor=south]{$=$}(c.south);}
```